# Visualforce page that is accessible from both a detail and list view button

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a visualforce page with 2 constructors

```
public customExtension(ApexPages.StandardSetController stdSetController) {

public customExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){
```

The page is defined a

```
apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true" standardController="Job_Application__c"
tabStyle="Job_Application__c" extensions="customExtension" recordSetVar="varRecords">
```

I'm trying to make the page accessible from both a detail button to put on the objects standard layout and a list view button so it's accessible from a related list of objects on the parent record.  If I remove the recordSetVar from the page definition I can define a detail button but not a list view and of course vise versa.  Is there a way to make this work without having to define two different pages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need separate `Visualforce Pages`, because the only difference is `recordSetVar`. You can put the entire body into a `Visualforce Component` in the spirit of [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). I omitted irrelevant attributes for brevity.

**Detail**

```
<apex:page standardController="Job_Application__c" extensions="MyExtension"
    recordSetVar="applications">

    <c:jobApplicationWidget someParam="{!someProperty}" />

</apex:page>
```

**List**

```
<apex:page standardController="Job_Application__c" extensions="MyExtension">

    <c:jobApplicationWidget someParam="{!someProperty}" />

</apex:page>
```